# Why lower bound is used in functional interfaces

Tags: java, generics, java-8, option-type, bounded-wildcard

The usage of lower bound in collections context is more or less clear to me (see [PECS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)). Not so with functional interfaces in Java. E.g. Why Optional.map method has the signature with lower type bound:

```
<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper);
```

What is the advantage of using *super* here and why the code below does not compile?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<? super BigDecimal, ? extends Number> mapper = dec -> dec
        .divide(BigDecimal.TEN)
        .doubleValue();
    BigDecimal bigD = BigDecimal.ONE;
    //works
    Optional.of(bigD).map(mapper);

    Number number = BigDecimal.ONE;
    // the following does not compile,
    // despite Number is super type of BigDecimal
    Optional.of(number).map(mapper);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the lower bound in the `mapper` parameter to `map` is to expand the range of acceptable `Function`s, to include not just those `Function`s that have *exactly* `T`, but also those types of which `T` might be a subclass.  E.g. such an `Optional<BigDecimal>` may accept not just a `Function<BigDecimal, Number>`, but a `Function<Number, Number>`, because a `BigDecimal` is a `Number`.  Such a function should be able to operate on a `BigDecimal` because it takes a `Number`.

Your line `Optional.of(number).map(mapper);` doesn't compile because here `T` is `Number`, not `BigDecimal`.  Attempting to pass in a `Function` whose `T` is `BigDecimal` doesn't match the signature -- `BigDecimal` is not a supertype of `Number`.  Your attempt to take advantage of `? super T` here fails because you've used a different `T`, not because it failed `? super T` somehow.  Those are two different concepts.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it now. My local mapper variable declaration used `super` keyword, which is obviously not needed, but was generated by the IDE